# Animate multiple point along routes using Mapbox-GL.JS

Tags: javascript, html, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am having problems with following example :
[Animate a point along a route](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/animate-point-along-route/)
What I am trying to achieve is to make another point and routes in the same map container.
What I tried so far is this

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicGFwYWJ1Y2t0IiwiYSI6ImNqa2k3azQ1dzA1Zmgza3B1czIxOGhhaW4ifQ.h5OT3NaQf0vcxx3g1q1cXw';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [118.0148634, -2.548926],
    zoom: 4.1
});
var route = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                   [117.66769409179686,3.2913401805277034],[117.75009155273438,3.2419820359767444],
                   [117.81188964843751,3.2008484073844365],[117.93273925781249,3.1514858749293237],
                   [118.048095703125,3.0637245031869744],[118.20190429687501,2.9649843693339677],
                   [118.35571289062499,2.855262784366583],[118.443603515625,2.789424777005989],
                   [118.597412109375,2.67419944615503],[118.817138671875,2.4656692707025543],
                   [118.93798828125,2.191238104506552],[118.97644042968749,1.9442068658308456],
                   [119.0643310546875,1.6477220517969353],[119.13574218749999,1.334718132769963],
                   [119.15222167968751,1.0051974541602744],[119.05334472656249,0.5987439850125229],
                   [118.9215087890625,0.29113644247137116],[118.8006591796875,-0.027465819260582135],
                   [118.597412109375,-0.5163504323777461],[118.27880859375001,-0.8953492997435784],
                   [118.16894531249999,-1.219390359762202],[117.83935546874999,-1.6641946615712557],
                   [117.7349853515625,-1.8618548574369598],[117.65258789062499,-2.0485136203038063],
                   [117.40539550781249,-2.67968661580376],[117.07580566406249,-3.2721456350750127],
                   [116.7572021484375,-3.8806964824972487],[116.44958496093749,-4.209464815163466],
                   [115.7574462890625,-4.335456463573485],[115.213623046875,-4.510714125698484],
                   [114.6533203125,-4.647604837557583],[114.1864013671875,-4.70235372255946],
                   [113.79089355468749,-4.7242520745232515],[113.4228515625,-4.8118385341739005],
                   [112.9669189453125,-4.8282597468669755],[112.28576660156249,-4.844680562025358],
                   [111.104736328125,-4.855627550617055],[110.7366943359375,-4.855627550617055],
                   [110.19287109375,-4.855627550617055],[109.60510253906249,-4.926778627933801],
                   [109.00634765625,-5.00339434502215],[108.4075927734375,-5.036226914872183],
                   [108.116455078125,-5.189423479732417],[107.5177001953125,-5.369928743247035],
                   [107.061767578125,-5.473831889192786],[106.76513671875,-5.544913134097361],
                   [106.44653320312499,-5.626919311742117],[106.248779296875,-5.747174076651375],
                   [106.1444091796875,-5.807291968003861],[106.02948188781738,-5.882003409958776]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {},
          "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                      [-252.99316406250003,-5.932972207945653],[-252.92724609374997,-5.774501181937723],
                      [-252.872314453125,-5.697981985463135],[-252.8118896484375,-5.572249801113899],
                      [-252.7789306640625,-5.484768018141262],[-252.7294921875,-5.353521355337321],
                      [-252.66357421875,-5.244127581489528],[-252.57568359374997,-5.112829778499449],
                      [-252.509765625,-5.00339434502215],[-252.42187499999997,-4.872047700241915],
                      [-252.2900390625,-4.740675384778361],[-252.11425781249997,-4.653079918274038],
                      [-252.00439453125,-4.54357027937176],[-251.78466796875,-4.434044005032582],
                      [-251.65283203125003,-4.34641127533318],[-251.45507812499997,-4.171115454867424],
                      [-251.16943359375,-4.083452772038619],[-251.03759765625,-3.9738609758391017],
                      [-250.90576171875,-3.8204080831949407],[-250.70800781249997,-3.688855143147035],
                      [-250.42236328125,-3.579212785860631],[-250.31250000000003,-3.513421045640032],
                      [-250.13671875,-3.3818237353282767],[-249.87304687499997,-3.2940822283128046],
                      [-249.697265625,-3.118576216781991],[-249.697265625,-2.943040910055132]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
};

// A single point that animates along the route.
// Coordinates are initially set to origin.
var point = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [117.66769409179686,3.2913401805277034]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-252.99316406250003,-5.932972207945653]
            }
        }

    ]
};

// Calculate the distance in kilometers between route start/end point.
for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
   var lineDistance = turf.lineDistance(route.features[0], 'kilometers');
}
   console.log(lineDistance) 


var arc = [];

// Number of steps to use in the arc and animation, more steps means
// a smoother arc and animation, but too many steps will result in a
// low frame rate
var steps = 1000;

// Draw an arc between the `origin` & `destination` of the two points
for (var i = 0; i < lineDistance; i += lineDistance / steps) {
    var segment = turf.along(route.features[0], i, 'kilometers');
    arc.push(segment.geometry.coordinates);
}

// Update the route with calculated arc coordinates
route.features[0].geometry.coordinates = arc;

// Used to increment the value of the point measurement against the route.
var counter = 0;

map.on('load', function () {
    // Add a source and layer displaying a point which will be animated in a circle.
    map.addSource('route', {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": route
    });

    map.addSource('point', {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": point
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "route",
        "source": "route",
        "type": "line",
        "paint": {
            "line-width": 1,
            "line-color": "#007cbf"
        }
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "point",
        "source": "point",
        "type": "symbol",
        "layout": {
            "icon-image": "airport-15",
            "icon-rotate": ["get", "bearing"],
            "icon-rotation-alignment": "map",
            "icon-allow-overlap": true,
            "icon-ignore-placement": true
        }
    });

    function animate() {
        // Update point geometry to a new position based on counter denoting
        // the index to access the arc.

        for(i=0;i < 2;i++) {
            point.features[i].properties.bearing = turf.bearing(
                turf.point(route.features[i].geometry.coordinates[counter >= steps ? counter - 1 : counter]),
                turf.point(route.features[i].geometry.coordinates[counter >= steps ? counter : counter + 1])
            );  
        }
        

        point.features[0].geometry.coordinates = route.features[0].geometry.coordinates[counter];
        // Update the source with this new data.
        map.getSource('point').setData(point);

        // Request the next frame of animation so long the end has not been reached.
        if (counter < steps) {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }

        counter = counter + 1;
    }

    document.getElementById('replay').addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Set the coordinates of the original point back to origin
        point.features[0].geometry.coordinates = origin;

        // Update the source layer
        map.getSource('point').setData(point);

        // Reset the counter
        counter = 0;

        // Restart the animation.
        animate(counter);
    });

    // Start the animation.
    animate(counter);
});
```

```css
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 30px;
}

.overlay button {
    font:600 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #3386c0;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.overlay button:hover {
    background-color:#4ea0da;
}
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
#map { top:0; bottom:0; width:100%;height: 600px }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Animate a point along a route</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.50.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.50.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   
</head>
<body>
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/turf/v2.0.0/turf.min.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card text-white">
      <h5 class="card-header bg-info">Featured</h5>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id='map'></div>
            <div class='overlay'>
                <button id='replay'>Replay</button>
            </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

After few things that I tried,the result of first attempt was Point 1 and Line 1 are reaching to the end.but Point 2 and Line 2 stopped after Point 1 and Line 1 are reaching to the end.
This is my 10th attempt. The other attempt was error on the loop.
What should I do with this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic problem is that the two routes are different lengths, so you go out of bounds on the coordinates for the shorter one while you're still going through the longer one. The snippet I inserted below accounts for that. Trying it just now, my edit completes without errors.

You'll probably want to tweak it a bit further, right now the shorter route completes much more quickly than the longer one, and moves much faster than the longer one. If you want them to appear to go the same speed, you'll need to use fewer steps for for the shorter one. If you want them to complete in the same amount of time, you'll need to add more points to the shorter one, or reduce the frequency with which the shorter one refreshes.

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicGFwYWJ1Y2t0IiwiYSI6ImNqa2k3azQ1dzA1Zmgza3B1czIxOGhhaW4ifQ.h5OT3NaQf0vcxx3g1q1cXw';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [118.0148634, -2.548926],
    zoom: 4.1
});
var route = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                   [117.66769409179686,3.2913401805277034],[117.75009155273438,3.2419820359767444],
                   [117.81188964843751,3.2008484073844365],[117.93273925781249,3.1514858749293237],
                   [118.048095703125,3.0637245031869744],[118.20190429687501,2.9649843693339677],
                   [118.35571289062499,2.855262784366583],[118.443603515625,2.789424777005989],
                   [118.597412109375,2.67419944615503],[118.817138671875,2.4656692707025543],
                   [118.93798828125,2.191238104506552],[118.97644042968749,1.9442068658308456],
                   [119.0643310546875,1.6477220517969353],[119.13574218749999,1.334718132769963],
                   [119.15222167968751,1.0051974541602744],[119.05334472656249,0.5987439850125229],
                   [118.9215087890625,0.29113644247137116],[118.8006591796875,-0.027465819260582135],
                   [118.597412109375,-0.5163504323777461],[118.27880859375001,-0.8953492997435784],
                   [118.16894531249999,-1.219390359762202],[117.83935546874999,-1.6641946615712557],
                   [117.7349853515625,-1.8618548574369598],[117.65258789062499,-2.0485136203038063],
                   [117.40539550781249,-2.67968661580376],[117.07580566406249,-3.2721456350750127],
                   [116.7572021484375,-3.8806964824972487],[116.44958496093749,-4.209464815163466],
                   [115.7574462890625,-4.335456463573485],[115.213623046875,-4.510714125698484],
                   [114.6533203125,-4.647604837557583],[114.1864013671875,-4.70235372255946],
                   [113.79089355468749,-4.7242520745232515],[113.4228515625,-4.8118385341739005],
                   [112.9669189453125,-4.8282597468669755],[112.28576660156249,-4.844680562025358],
                   [111.104736328125,-4.855627550617055],[110.7366943359375,-4.855627550617055],
                   [110.19287109375,-4.855627550617055],[109.60510253906249,-4.926778627933801],
                   [109.00634765625,-5.00339434502215],[108.4075927734375,-5.036226914872183],
                   [108.116455078125,-5.189423479732417],[107.5177001953125,-5.369928743247035],
                   [107.061767578125,-5.473831889192786],[106.76513671875,-5.544913134097361],
                   [106.44653320312499,-5.626919311742117],[106.248779296875,-5.747174076651375],
                   [106.1444091796875,-5.807291968003861],[106.02948188781738,-5.882003409958776]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {},
          "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                      [-252.99316406250003,-5.932972207945653],[-252.92724609374997,-5.774501181937723],
                      [-252.872314453125,-5.697981985463135],[-252.8118896484375,-5.572249801113899],
                      [-252.7789306640625,-5.484768018141262],[-252.7294921875,-5.353521355337321],
                      [-252.66357421875,-5.244127581489528],[-252.57568359374997,-5.112829778499449],
                      [-252.509765625,-5.00339434502215],[-252.42187499999997,-4.872047700241915],
                      [-252.2900390625,-4.740675384778361],[-252.11425781249997,-4.653079918274038],
                      [-252.00439453125,-4.54357027937176],[-251.78466796875,-4.434044005032582],
                      [-251.65283203125003,-4.34641127533318],[-251.45507812499997,-4.171115454867424],
                      [-251.16943359375,-4.083452772038619],[-251.03759765625,-3.9738609758391017],
                      [-250.90576171875,-3.8204080831949407],[-250.70800781249997,-3.688855143147035],
                      [-250.42236328125,-3.579212785860631],[-250.31250000000003,-3.513421045640032],
                      [-250.13671875,-3.3818237353282767],[-249.87304687499997,-3.2940822283128046],
                      [-249.697265625,-3.118576216781991],[-249.697265625,-2.943040910055132]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
};

// A single point that animates along the route.
// Coordinates are initially set to origin.
var point = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [117.66769409179686,3.2913401805277034]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-252.99316406250003,-5.932972207945653]
            }
        }

    ]
};

// Calculate the distance in kilometers between route start/end point.
for(i=0;i<2;i++) {
   var lineDistance = turf.lineDistance(route.features[0], 'kilometers');
}
   console.log(lineDistance) 


var arc = [];

// Number of steps to use in the arc and animation, more steps means
// a smoother arc and animation, but too many steps will result in a
// low frame rate
var steps = 1000;

// Draw an arc between the `origin` & `destination` of the two points
for (var i = 0; i < lineDistance; i += lineDistance / steps) {
    var segment = turf.along(route.features[0], i, 'kilometers');
    arc.push(segment.geometry.coordinates);
}

// Update the route with calculated arc coordinates
route.features[0].geometry.coordinates = arc;

// Used to increment the value of the point measurement against the route.
var counter = 0;

map.on('load', function () {
    // Add a source and layer displaying a point which will be animated in a circle.
    map.addSource('route', {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": route
    });

    map.addSource('point', {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": point
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "route",
        "source": "route",
        "type": "line",
        "paint": {
            "line-width": 1,
            "line-color": "#007cbf"
        }
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "point",
        "source": "point",
        "type": "symbol",
        "layout": {
            "icon-image": "airport-15",
            "icon-rotate": ["get", "bearing"],
            "icon-rotation-alignment": "map",
            "icon-allow-overlap": true,
            "icon-ignore-placement": true
        }
    });

    function animate(featureIdx, cntr) {
        // Update point geometry to a new position based on counter denoting
        // the index to access the arc.
        if (cntr >= route.features[featureIdx].geometry.coordinates.length-1){
          return;
        }
        point.features[featureIdx].geometry.coordinates = route.features[featureIdx].geometry.coordinates[cntr];


        point.features[featureIdx].properties.bearing = turf.bearing(
            turf.point(route.features[featureIdx].geometry.coordinates[cntr >= steps ? cntr - 1 : cntr]),
            turf.point(route.features[featureIdx].geometry.coordinates[cntr >= steps ? cntr : cntr + 1])
        );  
        

        // Update the source with this new data.
        map.getSource('point').setData(point);

        // Request the next frame of animation so long the end has not been reached.
        if (cntr < steps) {
            requestAnimationFrame(function(){animate(featureIdx, cntr+1);});
        }

    }

    document.getElementById('replay').addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Set the coordinates of the original point back to origin
        point.features[0].geometry.coordinates = origin;

        // Update the source layer
        map.getSource('point').setData(point);

        // Reset the counter
        cntr = 0;

        // Restart the animation.
        animate(0,cntr);
        animate(1,cntr)
    });

    // Start the animation.
    animate(0, 0);
    animate(1, 0);
});
```

```css
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 30px;
}

.overlay button {
    font:600 12px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #3386c0;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.overlay button:hover {
    background-color:#4ea0da;
}
body { margin:0; padding:0; }
#map { top:0; bottom:0; width:100%;height: 600px }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Animate a point along a route</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.50.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.50.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   
</head>
<body>
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/turf/v2.0.0/turf.min.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card text-white">
      <h5 class="card-header bg-info">Featured</h5>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id='map'></div>
            <div class='overlay'>
                <button id='replay'>Replay</button>
            </div>
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you ,Paul. This is the answer i was looking for . The plane doesn't have to be appear in the same speed , because on my database,there is a timestamp . When the object has arrived at the destination,it should stopped. Once again, Thank you

Comment: Mapbox Token is invalid.  Can you update this answer with a valid one?

Comment: @lololololol Are you asking for an API key leak?... 